# How to decode a week code (ISO week date)

Tags: mfc, timespan, ctime

Is there a way on how to decode a week code or ISO week date using `CTime` ? I am currently creating an expiration date that is based on week code. I'm having a hard time adding the `CTime` and `CTimeSpan` (`shelf_life`) because the output is not accurate.

If the `shelf_life` is 6 months, my output is accurate. But when the `shelf_life` is more than a year, the output is 4 months overdue.

This is my code:

```
CTime tt, t11;
CString Cweek, Cyear;
int yy, mm, wknum, yrnum;

tt = CTime::GetCurrentTime();
yy = tt.GetYear();
mm = tt.GetMonth();

wknum = atoi(tt.Format("%U"));
yrnum = atoi(tt.Format("%y"));
t11 = CTime(yy, mm, 1, 0, 0, 0);
if (t11.GetDayOfWeek() == 4)
    wknum = wknum ++;

Cweek.Format("%02d", wknum);
Cyear.Format("%02d", yrnum);

CTimeSpan shelf_no = CTimeSpan(atoi(view->m_pODBCPartsNo->m_shelf_life), 0, 0, 0);
CTime expiration_date = tt + shelf_no;
```

Comment: You're using `atoi` on `m_shelf_life`, what does that string look like?

Comment: @MarkRansom i'm getting the data of shelf_life in database

Comment: That doesn't tell me anything.  What is the format of the string?

Comment: @MarkRansom `atoi` converts string into integer and `m_shelf_life` is the column in my database

Comment: I've looked at your code and I don't see any obvious problems.  I therefore conclude that the problem is in the data being fed to the code.  Since you refuse to share a single example of that input, **nobody** can help you.  You need a [mre], emphasis on the "complete".  Good luck to you.

Comment: @PJiwon You are being asked to show an example of a text string that you are using. Eg `"10/12/2022T12:10:55"`. You tell us where it comes from ( a database record) but not the content of the string.

Comment: `wknum = wknum ++` - That cannot be right. It *might* do the right thing, but really, with the exception of the final two characters, the entire expression is just a giant no-op. That's very confusing code. Speaking of confusing code, [`std::chrono`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/chrono) is the opposite. Might want to use that for your date/time calculations instead. Then again, I've recommended `std::chrono` twice already. Maybe you just don't want robust, clean code.